# Mask layer tensorflow exponentially increases training time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use a Masking layer from tensorflow in my neural network in order to ignore padding.
The problem is if I insert this layer, the training time goes from 2 minutes per epoch to 3 hours per epoch.

I use as input a vector of size `(584366, 200, 1)`  meaning 58k sequences of 200 timesteps. The first 100 are all padding ( I did this because the test set I'm being evaluated uses inputs of size 200 timesteps, but i still wanted to train my NN on shorter sequences ).

Is it normal? Or what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
def build_biLSTM(input_shape, output_shape):
    # Build the neural network layer by layer
    input_layer = tfkl.Input(shape=input_shape, name='Input')

    masking = tfkl.Masking(mask_value = -1,input_shape = (input_shape[0],input_shape[1]))(input_layer)

    # Feature extractor
    bilstm = tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(masking)
    bilstm = tfkl.Bidirectional(tfkl.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))(bilstm)
    dropout = tfkl.Dropout(.5, seed=seed)(bilstm)
    
    output_layer = tfkl.Conv1D(output_shape[1], 3, padding = "same", name ="Conv1D")(dropout)
    
    cropping = dropout.shape[1] - output_shape[0]
    

    output_layer = tfkl.Cropping1D((0,cropping), name = "Cropping")(output_layer)

    # Connect input and output through the Model class
    model = tfk.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='model')

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss=tfk.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tfk.optimizers.Adam())

    # Return the model
    return model
```

I use this function to build my neural network

The masking layer produces this effect only if it recognizes the `mask_value` in the samples

Answer (score 0):

Using a Masking layer in TensorFlow to ignore padding can significantly increase training time. However, it's not normal for the training time to go from 2 minutes per epoch to 3 hours per epoch. Here are a few possible reasons and suggestions:

1. Batch size: Try reducing the batch size, even to 1, and see if it improves the training time. Larger batch sizes might be causing the issue when combined with the Masking layer.
2. Performance impact: Masking layers can sometimes affect the performance of LSTM layers. You can try removing the Masking layer and using padding in your data instead to see if it improves the training time.
3. Data size: Your input data size is quite large (584366, 200, 1), so ensure that you have enough computational resources to handle it. Consider reducing the data dimensionality or using sampling techniques to make training more efficient.

I hope these suggestions help you address the training time issue. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, regarding batch size I will try it, removing the masking layer result in better perfomance but my NN will process also padding, also, what do you mean by sampling techniques?